# Getting offline GPG master keys right

Tags: gpg

I've been following the directions [here](https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair/) for creating a GPG key and storing the "master" key offline.  Everything went exactly as the directions said.  However, after [the directions on how to remove the master key](https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair/#transforming-your-master-keypair-into-your-laptop-keypair), I tested `gpg --import public.gpg-key private.gpg-key` to see if it would restore the master key to my keyring.  But after doing that, `gpg --list-secret-keys` still showed `sec#` for the master key, indicating that the master key isn't there.

What am I doing wrong?

(In the meantime, since I'd backed up my `$HOME/.gnupg` before the step of removing the master key, I restored it, made sure it was good, added a copy of that `.gnupg`  to the external media on which the master key exists (in addition to all the files created by following the directions), then re-deleted the master key.  I figure that in an emergency I can temporarily replace the my `.gnupg` with the copy I'd saved.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the instructions and it works for me, using either GPG 1.4.16 or 2.1.11. Could you have possibly misspelled the commands in "Exporting the Final Product"? There are some unnecessary `'\>'`-s in there.

You can check the contents of `private.gpg-key` with `gpg --list-packets <private.gpg-key`. E.g., when I pipe that into `egrep "(^:secret|protect IV)"`, I see:

```
:secret key packet:
    protect IV:  4e 1b 98 12 19 f6 fa 16 36 e3 4d 9d 9a 02 e6 52
:secret sub key packet:
    protect IV:  96 f8 68 65 c8 b8 f0 d6 59 59 73 e1 63 30 f5 21
:secret sub key packet:
    protect IV:  e1 43 e4 25 49 15 c5 ad 1e 09 75 cf c6 1f d0 4c
:secret sub key packet:
    protect IV:  af da 37 82 dc f0 f3 24 6e b7 9f 4f 77 70 84 25
```

This shows the file contains the master signing key and 3 subkeys. When the file is created with `--export-secret-subkeys` instead of `--export-secret-keys`, the first IV is empty.